# Queries related to Django Signals

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

To begin with, Here Profile and Seller model is created when a User model is created through Signals.What I want to do is When profile model is first created or updated,I want all the fields of Seller model to be same as all fields of Profile.Similarly when I first created Seller model,I also want all fields of Profile Model to be same as that of Seller model.But,I couldn't figure out how to do?

```
from typing import Tuple
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.fields import DecimalField
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #cascade is for deleting the customer
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True,blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance,created,**kwargs):#Signal receivers must accept keyword arguments (**kwargs).
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def create_seller(sender, instance,created,**kwargs):#Signal receivers must accept keyword arguments (**kwargs).
    if created:
        Seller.objects.create(user=instance)

class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #cascade is for deleting the customer
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True,blank=True)
         
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `created=True` it means a `Profile` object is created. otherwise if `created=False` it means that a `Profile` object has been updated.

When `created=True` you need to create a `Seller` object and when `created=False` you need to update a `Seller` object.

You can do this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def update_or_create_seller(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Seller.objects.create(
            user=instance.user, 
            first_name=instance.first_name,
            second_name=instance.second_name,
            email=instance.email
        )
    else:
        seller = instance.user.seller
        seller.first_name = instance.first_name
        seller.last_name = instance.second_name
        seller.email = instance.email
        seller.save()
```

Also notice that unless you define `related_name` in your `OneToOneField`, Django will use **lowercased** model name to access related object. So, `instance.user.seller` should work.

Comment: It doesn't work at all instead gives me errors.But well you gave me idea and i solved it.

Comment: cannot query must be user instance